# All the members of my array are at the same memory location when they were created using new()

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

I have created a seven-by-seven array of pointers to "Timeslot" objects in my constructor, using new, like so:

```
Timeslot ***schedule;

Schedule::Schedule(void)
{
    schedule = new Timeslot**[DAYS]();
    for(int day = 0; day < DAYS; day++){
        schedule[day] = new Timeslot*[TIMESLOTS]();
        for(int time = 0; time < TIMESLOTS; time++){
            schedule[day][time] = new Timeslot();
        }
    }
}
```

When i edit one Timeslot object, the change is made to all of them. I have tried to google this problem, but all instances i could find were people not using `new`.

Since i was asked, the change i'm making to the timeslot object that is being propagated to all of them is i'm flagging a bit in a bitmask, using a method of the Timeslot class.

```
void Timeslot::book(int instructor){
    bitmask = bitmask | instructormasks[instructor];
}
```

I have, since posting this question, discovered that yes each timeslot object IS getting its own unique memory address, and somehow the bitmask is being flagged in all of them. I'm looking into it now.

Comment: What change are you making and how the class is defined and implemented?

Comment: IMHO that should be allocating a new Timeslot() to every day/time combination. Maybe you are doing something wrong when changing a timeslot?

Comment: And while at it, why are you not using std::vector and/or std::map?

Comment: A small (but important) note: Your `for` loops loop one to many!

Comment: How did you determine that "change is made to all of them"? That code might have a bug giving you this impression.

Comment: By the way, you don't need `()` when `new`ing arrays of pointers (`schedule = new Timeslot**[DAYS]();`) and not even when `new`ing arrays of objects if you are calling their default constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no *technical* problem with your code. No buffer overflows or etc. And, obviously, `operator new` should return distinct addresses for different objects unless they were explicitly freed.

Then the problem is most probably in the rest of your code.

- Are you using a standard heap (`new/delete`)?
- Is `bitmask` a **non-static member** of `Timeslot` class?

Anyway, your code is somewhat over-complicated. It's useful to allocate arrays of pointer-to-pointer-to-pointers in case you're really going to "play" with it, i.e. in runtime re-allocate pointers, or intentionally make several pointers to point on the same object. It's also useful in case you deal with huge objects, and don't want to demand long contiguous memory blocks.

But you say you have in total 7x7 = 49 objects, which are (supposedly) tiny. Then just use one "static" array:

```
Timeslot schedule[DAYS][TIMESLOTS];
```

Comment: Yep, turns out i was declaring bitmask as global all along. Don't i feel silly.

Answer (score 3):

You have a buffer overflow here:

```
for (int day = 0; day <= DAYS; day++)
    schedule[day] = // rest of code
```

and here

```
for(int time = 0; time <= TIMESLOTS; time++)
    schedule[day][time] = //rest of code
```

that could be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Timeslot ***schedule; - THAT could be the cause ;)

Comment: there's no buffer overflow here!

Comment: @valdo - there was an overflow before the question was edited.

Comment: @valdo, yeah, take that -1 back! :D

Comment: @Shahbaz: I'm trying to take it back, but it's locked :(

Comment: @Shahbaz: I'll be allowed to re-vote iff you edit your answer :)

Comment: @valdo, I did, but don't sweat it, who cares!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like you are defining a 3D array when you need a 2D one.

```
Timeslot ***schedule; // 3D array


schedule = new Timeslot**[DAYS]() // 2D array of 1D arrays? Or is it the other way around?
```

I haven't used C arrays for years so I am not sure what the effect of this would be in your initialization loops, but it's worth looking at.

Comment: Since he is `new`ing in three levels, maybe he does need a 3d array.

Comment: @Shahbaz could be, but maybe when he looks at his `Timeslots` in his "7*7 array" he looks in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You have a global variable `schedule` which is initialized in the `Schedule` constructor.
Maybe you're doing the same thing with `bitmask`. Make sure that `bitmask` is a non-static member of `Timeslot`.